# connecting outline rendering in open gl es

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm trying to create my first *2d game* for the android platform using Java and Open GL es. Now my problem is that my game needs a water element and I decided to do it so that the water is made up of little circles with an outline so that they look like cartoony drops of water but when two or more of these little drops get next to each other(and intersect a little) I want to have their outlines connect thus forming a bigger drop. So my question is, is this possible(the dynamically connecting outlines) and if it is could anyone tell me how to do it or link me to a tutorial or something?

Here's a little drawing I made in paint to illustrate what I'd like to achieve:

[image]

Comment: FYI, a common term for this kind of rendering is [*metaballs*](https://www.google.com/search?q=metaballs). It may lead you to some helpful tutorials.

Comment: Thanks Tim I didn't know the correct term for it that's why I couldn't find anything online.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to do this with the stencil buffer, assuming your device supports it.

The inner part of the circles would write into the stencil buffer.
The outer part of the circles would only write where the stencil buffer is zero.

You could probably do it the same way (or similarly) with a shader and a colour buffer/FBO as well.

Comment: I think you mean "the outer part writes where buffer is **zero**", right?

Comment: Thanks Ravuya I'll try this out tomorrow if I get some spare time.